# Can I print a custom paper on standsard size in word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word document that was created using 9 X 6 as the custom paper. I dont have that size paper just the normal 8 x 11.5. How can I setup word to print the document with its current size but on the normal paper?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want Word to scale (shrink) the document when you print it you should disable zoom or scaling in the print options.

For Microsoft Word 2003, go to Office Icon -> Print. In the dialog that appears, select "No Scaling" for the "Scale to paper size option". Note that depending on what your printer limits and your document margins are, this could leave parts of your document cropped off.

If I misunderstood your question, and you do want it to scale (i.e. fit on 8.5" x 11" letter paper) simply select "Letter" under the same option mentioned above.

Comment: So whats happening when I print the printer doesnt find the page so i change it to letter but then it adjusts all the pages and sizes to fit letter.  I want it to still print on the custom size but just to the standards size paper.

Comment: I'm still a little confused - so you are sending a unscaled version, but the printer (not word) is auto-scaling it down?

Comment: I try to sned it to the printer but it errors out because I dont have that size paper.  If i change the paper size to "Letter" in word it scales everything to 8 x 10.

Comment: In the same print dialog, you should click on the properties for your particular, and make sure the output is Letter size.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your document
2. Go to the `File` tab
3. Go to the `Print` menu item
4. You will see a list of options and a preview to the right. Under the options you will see `Page Setup` click it and a window will open
5. Go to the `Paper` tab
6. From the `Paper Size` dropdown select `Letter` or manually input Width = 8.5 and height = 11
7. Press OK
8. Assuming the proper printer is selected press `Print`