# MS Word Printing Help 2010

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word document that was created using 9 X 6 as the custom paper.  I dont have that size paper just the normal 8 x 11.5.  How can I setup word to print the document with its current size but on the normal paper?

Comment: Double posting of [Can I print a custom paper on standsard size in word?](http://superuser.com/questions/612349/can-i-print-a-custom-paper-on-standsard-size-in-word)